# View Deleted Records in Advance Search Layout SugarCRM CE 6.5.x

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

By adding a custom check box field (non-db) can we show in ListView the deleted and non-deleted records for Administrator?

A normal User only needs to show the non-deleted records in list view.

Can any one guide me on this?

Comment: Yes. You can show deleted records in list view. Did you try something to make it work?

Comment: Hi 
i got few solution from these below links

http://blog.innovsystems.com/sugarcrm/how-retrieve-deleted-records-sugarcrm

http://urdhva-tech.blogspot.in/2013/02/extending-list-view-query.html

i want to do (remove deleted=o) in $mainquery, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Hi #sAcH, 
tried and added below 
$this->params['custom_where'] = ' and tablename.deleted =1';
Im able to get all(del and non del), 
but how can i get only deleted list?

Comment: If you are showing deleted modules for particular module let say 'contacts' then if(module=='contacts' and view = 'list') (update the $where condition by removing shwing parameter)

Comment: Hi you mean, writing another action, via controllers??
cant we get deleted records by modify/customize the list view query itself
hope im clear..thnks for your guidance @sAcH

Comment: BTW correction in the above comment 
$this->params['custom_where'] = ' or tablename.deleted =1';

Comment: cant we customize in view.list.php like remove deleted=0

Comment: No.. You have to do modification in Query itself in SugarBean.php file.. Just update the where condition for particular module

Comment: Hi @sAcH, 
done in different way, dnt know that is proper way or not, i got succeed and boss said ook..

thanks
naren